# Plotly Dash : Persist or store state of Graph and DataTable component

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a multi-page/tab dash application and often switch between pages/tab. I have a `plotly Graph`, a `mapbox` component that is updated on button click.

I'd like to be able to save the state of the `graph` and reference it in other tabs/functions. With inputs and others fields, I have used the `persistence` property, however, I do not see a way to do the same for `Graph figure`.

```
layout = html.Div([

            dash_table.DataTable(id='dt-table'),
            dcc.Graph(id='map-graph1'),
            dbc.Button("Run", id="run-button"),

]),

# Update map graph

@app.callback(Output("map-graph1", "figure"),
          [
              Input("address", "value"),
              Input("type", "value"),
              Input("button", "n_clicks")
          ]
         )
def update_graph(address, type, n_clicks):

    data = []

    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....

    data.append({

                "type": "scattermapbox",
                "lat": [lat],
                "lon": [lng],
                "name": "Location",
                "showlegend": False,
                "hoverinfo": "text",
                "mode": "markers",
                "marker": {
                    "symbol": "circle",
                    "size": 12,
                    "opacity": 0.7
                    }
                }
    )

    # Get lat long from geocoding api
    if n_clicks:

       result = calc_func(address, type)

       # Property Location
       data.append({
                    "type": "scattermapbox",
                    "lat": [Lat],
                    "lon": [Long],
                    "hovertext": price,
                    "textfont": {"size": 22},
                    "textposition": 'top-right',
                    "showlegend": False,
                    "hoverinfo": "text",
                    "mode": "text+markers",
                    "marker": {
                               "symbol": "suitcase",
                               "size": 28,
                               "opacity": 0.7
                    }
                   }
        )


       layout = {
                 "autosize": True,
                 "hovermode": "closest",
                 "mapbox": {
                            "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                            "bearing": 0,
                            "center": {
                                       "lat": layout_lat,
                                       "lon": layout_lon
                            },
                            "pitch": 0,
                            "zoom": zoom,
                            "style": "outdoors",
                  }
                 }

return {"data": data, "layout": layout}

# Update DataTable
@app.callback(Output("comps-table", "data"),
          [
              Input("address", "value"),
              Input("type", "value"),
              Input("comps-button", "n_clicks")
          ]
         )
def update_table(address, type, n_clicks):

    if n_clicks:

       result = calc_func(address, type, market)
       result_df = result['df_lease']

       df = pd.DataFrame(result_df, columns = ['Address','Type','Market'])

        df = df[df['Type'] == "Type1"]
        df_data = df.to_dict('rows')

        return (df_data)

    else:

        return (no_update)
```